# Reading excel values as seconds and convert to minutes

Tags: python-3.x, excel, datetime, converters

I am currently writing a lager script to ease my life.

Right now I am reading raw values from cells from an excel.
So far so good.

These numbers need to be interpreted as seconds and then converted into minutes.

I tried my best with datetime but no luck.

Any suggestions?

```
elif auswahl == '2':
        print("Some user friendly-text:")
        excel_download = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'/Path/to/excel.xlsx')
        sheet = excel_download.active
        Grund_1 = sheet['B2'].value
        Grund_2 = sheet['B3'].value
        Grund_3 = sheet['B4'].value
        Grund_4 = sheet['B5'].value
        Grund_5 = sheet['B6'].value
        Grund_6 = sheet['B7'].value
        Zeit_in_Sekunden_1 = sheet['C2'].value
        Zeit_in_Sekunden_2 = sheet['C3'].value
        Zeit_in_Sekunden_3 = sheet['C4'].value
        Zeit_in_Sekunden_4 = sheet['C5'].value
        Zeit_in_Sekunden_5 = sheet['C6'].value
        Zeit_in_Sekunden_6 = sheet['C7'].value

        print("Du warst heute für", Zeit_in_Sekunden_1, Grund_1, "!")
        break
```

My idea:

```
raw_seconds_from_C2 = sheet['C2'].value
```

Then somehow convert to minutes from `raw_seconds_from_C2`

I am really out of ideas as I then need to put the converted minutes into a `print()`.

Comment: You could try this ```c2_minutes = sheet['C2'].value / 60```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the value by 60 to obtain minutes from seconds:

```py
c2_minutes = sheet['C2'].value / 60
```

Thanks to @Alonso's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347906/solved-reading-excel-values-as-seconds-and-convert-to-minutes#comment126112899_71347906) on the question.